# WADDiagnosticInfrastructureLogsTable failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

My Azure **WADDiagnosticInfrastructureLogsTable** is heavily overloaded with this error:

```
WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://DDDDDDDDD.blob.core.windows.net) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have discussed exact same behavior in past in my [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/01/20/winhttpgetproxyforurl-failed-error-winhttp-autodetection-failed-12180-error-message-in-windows-azure-infrastructure-log.aspx). I just checked and found this is still the case even now.